# How to open in new tab when clicking JQuery auto complete search results?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using JQuery auto completer plugin along with Rails 3. I have a search bar which shows different site names. on click this auto complete results, corresponding sites page gets displayed.

My issues is I want to get the sites url opened in new tab. How is this possible.

```
sites.each do |site|
  suggestions << {:text => "site: #{site.name}", :url => url} 
end
render :json => suggestions
```

Comment: Removed Rails from tags, since this is really a HTML/JS question.

Comment: Are you using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ or another plugin? Please mention it as jQuery UI if this is the case. jQuery != jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Rails. You could use
`window.open(url)` to handle this via Javascript, since you're already using jQuery.

Example for a link:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    window.open(this.href); 
    return false;
});
```